# Does it make sense that Bronn can get a castle by pretty much robbing?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Bronn from *Game of Thrones* put a crossbow and aimed it at both Jaime and Tyrion, Hand of the King, demanding a castle.

Does this make sense?

Usually, robbing is done to steal wallets or things whose property is far away from governments' control.

Also how to enforce the deal? I don't kill you, I got Riverrun. After he's not killed, Tyrion can always report the crime of coercing the Hand of the Queen to the queen and get Bronn killed instead.

Imagine I put a gun on the US president and demand the White House. It wouldn't work, right? Even if the president says yes, then what?

Comment: From what I remember, the whole Lannister family home, "Castral Rock" has been acquired by robbing.

Comment: robbing by attacking it. Not buy pointing gun to the owner making it promise to give it

Comment: No, the Lannisters ancester didn't attack Casterly Rock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here, but he is not simply robbing them. For some context:

- Bronn was technically hired by Cersei to kill Tyrion and Jaime and promised a castle. However, Bronn is not stupid, he knows that Cersei has little odds at this point (almost the whole realm is against her + dragons) and even if Cersei would win she is not trustworthy at all.
- Bronn has been promised a castle, title and even high-born marriage before by the lannisters. This got annuled then by another Lannister (Jaime). There are some obvious feelings of distrust here.
- Bronn is at that point known as a servant of the Lannisters and is thus in the heart of his enemy's encampment. He has not come to defect and fight on their side since Bronn has a habit of avoiding real danger if possible, and battles are risky. Add to that Daenerys' behavior of burning her enemies and he has very good reason not to get caught.

So what does he do there. He basically again demands the castle he was promised, and makes it clear he is not supporting Cersei. He keeps them on a distance with the crossbow for two reason: he may not get caught (per above) and he wants to stop them from weaseling out of the deal again (i.e. **only Bronn** does the talking).

Now, you have a point that it still is a deal made at <strike>gun</strike> arrowpoint. Given the little exposition at the end we can only guess at why Tyrion chose to honor it, though I think we can make a good guess: Tyrion has been shown personally to honor the 'A Lannister always pays his debts' motto. Bronn has shown quite some loyalty towards him and afterwards Jaime. The only times we saw his loyalty wavering was when it'd mean an almost certain death sentence (i.e. fight against the Mountain). Add to that they actually have a lot of fallen major and minor houses and they don't have their pick of the litter when it comes to new lords. So there is little reason not to honor him with a Castle.

Comment: Additionally, there is a scene between Tyrion and Bronn in the early seasons where Tyrion mentions that if Bronn would ever get paid to betray Tyrion, Tyrion will pay double of what they're offering him. Given that Tyrion hasn't ever crossed Bronn and has also stuck to the debt-repaying adage of the Lannisters, gives Bronn reason enough to know that Tyrion doesn't make deals he won't repay (or at the very least genuinely intend to)

Answer (score 7):

Bronn is actually respecting a deal made a while ago with Tyrion, who said that if Bronn was hired by someone to kill Tyrion, Bronn could the come to Tyrion and Tyrion would offer the double price to stay alive.

So, in this [situation](https://youtu.be/5nu6sPrL7DM?t=152), Cersei offered Bronn Riverrun to kill Tyrion, and Tyrion offered the double of Riverrun, Highgarden, to stay alive.

Bronn could kill Tyrion from afar, without warning him, but he remembered the deal and respected it.

A while ago, Tyrion was to be killed by the Moon clans (and Bronn was with Tyrion) and Tyrion made a deal with them, that if they don't kill him, he could provide them cool weapons. Tyrion honoured the deal, and Bronn witnessed it.

Your comparison with the US President and his White House is also wrong. Bronn is not earning Castral Rock or King's Landing, but Highgarden, which has apparently no Lord, so why not Bronn?

Comment: This answer makes more sense

Answer (score 3):

Admitted it makes little sense (just like him becoming master of coin while previously not even knowing what a bank is, but hey that's the later seasons for yea), but the way it works is that Tyrion and Jaime are Lannisters. And they always pay their debts... so a deal made under what circumstance it might be in is a deal honored by them (Tyrion has made deals in the show under a form of duress (Like when he was captured in the Eyrie, he feared death so he made a deal with the jailer...after he got freed he honored the deal without anything binding him to do so)

But admitted, it would be more logical for Tyrion to have his old friend killed because of the fact how untrustworthy he is....

Answer (score 1):

Bronn gives a good explanation for why this makes sense during the scene you mentioned:

**Jaime:**

> Riverrun will never belong to a cutthroat.

**Bronn:**

> No?  Who were your ancestors?  The ones who made your family rich?  They were f***ing cutthroats.  That’s how all the great houses started, isn’t it?  With a hard bastard who was good at killing people.  Kill a few hundred people they make you lord; kill a few thousand, they make you king.